# Is there a way to remove default padding from react native picker component?

Tags: react-native, padding, styling, picker

I want to start showing the text inside the picker component from the start without any padding applied. I researched but couldn't find a solution. I'm debugging in android.

My code:

```
<View style={[styles.pickerContainer]}>
            <Picker
              selectedValue={this.state.phoneCountryCode}
              style={[styles.pickerText(text),{backgroundColor:'transparent', width: 80 }]}
              itemStyle={{padding:0, backgroundColor:'yellow'}}
              mode="dropdown"
              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                this.setState({ phoneCountryCode: itemValue })
              }>
              {Constants.CountryCodes.map((item, index) => (
                <Picker.Item key={item} label={item.label} value={item.value} />
              ))}
            </Picker>
          </View>
```

Style:

```
pickerContainer:{
  marginTop: 10, 
  position: 'absolute', left:0, bottom:0, zIndex:10,
},
  pickerText:(text)=>({
  color:'gray',
  height: 40,
  textAlign: 'left',
  padding:0,
  margin: 0,
}),
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had same issue with Picker component, it's quite tricky to style it correctly, I'm leaving some of my findings.

use negative `marginLeft` to remove padding on the left.

use `width` and wrapper view to manage padding on right.

use `height` to fix vertical padding.

Just in case you can afford one dependency check some third-party components like
[this](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown)
it's highly customizable

PS: You may have figured it by now, but I'm still leaving a remark for anyone else.

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: Works for Android and I do not know if it works for IOS.

In my case it was sufficient to set margin to `-16` (as padding is set to 16 for picker) and to wrap picker into view with following things set in style: `overflow: 'hidden', justifyContent: 'center', display: 'flex'`.
Now it is possible to set up padding by setting up padding on view. BTW setting height on view also works for picker.

```
        <View
            style={{
              width: '70%',
              borderStyle: 'solid',
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: 'black',
              height: 20,
              padding: 6,
              overflow: 'hidden',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              display: 'flex',
            }}>
            <Picker
              mode="dropdown"
              style={{
                backgroundColor: 'yellow',
                margin: -16,
              }}
              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {}}>
              <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" style={{fontSize: 10}} />
              <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" style={{fontSize: 10}} />
            </Picker>
          </View>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked for me in July 2023.